# Bluemix 上の Python で sendgrid モジュール使用時にエラー ImportError: No module named sendgrid

Tags: python, bluemix

以下のコードをデプロイしようとすると、エラーで落ちてしまいます。
どうすれば、sendgridをBluemixにインストールできますか？教えてください。

**エラーメッセージ:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "server.py", line 10, in <module>
    import sendgrid
ImportError: No module named sendgrid
```

**現状のコード:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#! coding: UTF-8
import urllib2
import base64
import zlib
import json
import sys
import ssl
import datetime
import sendgrid
import sqlalchemy
from sqlalchemy import *
import ibm_db_sa.ibm_db_sa
db2 = sqlalchemy.create_engine('ibm_db_sa://dash013754:password@bluemix05.bluforcloud.com:50000/BLUDB')
metadata = MetaData()
users = Table('users', metadata, 
Column('user_id', Integer, primary_key = True),
Column('user_name', String(16), nullable = False),
Column('email_address', String(60), key='email'),
Column('password', String(20), nullable = False)
)
metadata.bind = db2
metadata.create_all()
users_table = Table('users', metadata, autoload=True, autoload_with=db2)
users_table

# using SendGrid's Python Library - https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-python
sg = sendgrid.SendGridClient(api_user, api_key)
message = sendgrid.Mail()
message.add_to("ntadashi@jp.ibm.com")
message.set_from("ntadashi@sendgrid.com")
message.set_subject("Sending with SendGrid is Fun")
message.set_html(stmt)

sg.send(message)
```

Comment: Bluemixはrequirements.txtを見てライブラリをインストールするようですが、こちらは作成されていますか？ http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/jp/cloud/library/cl-worldbank-charting-app/#1.4.1.Step3.PreparetodeploytheapplicationtoIBMBluemix|outline

Comment: 作成していません。そのせいでImportできないのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

sendgrid を使い始める際に `pip install sendgrid` 等のコマンドを実行したと思いますが、これはお手元の環境にそのパッケージが入っていないからです。同じことが Bluemix 上でも言えますから、仰る通りインストール作業が必要になります。

この作業は Bluemix の場合、requirements.txt に依存関係を記述することで行うようです。

[http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/jp/cloud/library/cl-worldbank-charting-app/](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/jp/cloud/library/cl-worldbank-charting-app/#1.4.1.Step3.PreparetodeploytheapplicationtoIBMBluemix%7Coutline)

> プロジェクトのルート・ディレクトリーに requirement.txt ファイルを追加します。requirement.txt ファイルには、グラフ生成アプリケーションを実行するために必要なすべての外部依存関係 (Django や PyMongo など) を含める必要があります。このアプリケーションが実行されたときに、requrement.txt ファイルが読み取られること、そしてこのファイルに記載されている依存関係がインストールされることが、Bluemix によって確実になります。

requirements.txt は Heroku 等でも使えますし、日本語の資料も多数見つかるかと思います。

---

sendgrid をはじめとする各種パッケージは [PyPi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi) というサイトに登録されています。 `pip install` もしくは `easy_install` すると、このサイトから最新バージョンを調べ、インストールします。

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/sendgrid

今回の場合も、Bluemix 上には sendgrid パッケージがないので、 PyPi 上から sendgrid パッケージをインストールすることになります。その上で、どのパッケージを選択するかを指示するのが requirements.txt ということになります。

よって、あなたが Bluemix 上で使いたい sendgrid のバージョンを記述する必要があります。

もし手元で使っているのと同じバージョンを指定したいのであれば、 `pip freeze` コマンドで requirements.txt と互換性のあるリストを出力できます。下記の記事をご一読ください。

[Python Tips：ライブラリをまとめてインストールしたい - Life with Python](http://www.lifewithpython.com/2014/03/python-install-multiple-modules-.html)

Comment: requirement.txtに Bluemix上のsendgridの記述をしようと思っているのですが、Sendgridのあとの数字がわかりません。バージョンですか？


Django==1.6.5
pymongo==2.7.1

Comment: はい、バージョン番号を書いてください。

Comment: すみません。Bluemix上のsendgridのバージョンがわからないのです。何度もすみません。

Comment: なるほど・・・回答に追記しました。

Comment: ありがとうございました。1.4.0でとおりました。ありがとうございます。